# why is /usr/include/boost missing

Tags: boost

I run

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

and yet I see nothing in my `/usr/include` directory for boost.

```
   0 upgraded, 27 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/78.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 276 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-dev:amd64.
(Reading database ... 503640 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-tools-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-tools-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-tools-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-atomic-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-atomic-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-atomic-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-chrono-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-chrono-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-chrono-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-context-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-context-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-context-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-coroutine-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-coroutine-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-coroutine-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-date-time-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-date-time-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-date-time-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-exception-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-exception-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-exception-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-filesystem-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-filesystem-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-filesystem-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-graph-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-graph-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-graph-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-graph-parallel-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-graph-parallel-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-graph-parallel-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-iostreams-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-iostreams-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-iostreams-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-locale-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-locale-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-locale-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-log-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-log-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-log-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-math-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-math-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-math-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-mpi-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-mpi-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-mpi-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-mpi-python-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-mpi-python-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-mpi-python-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-random-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-random-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-random-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-regex-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-regex-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-regex-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-serialization-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-serialization-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-serialization-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-signals-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-signals-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-signals-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-system-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-system-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-system-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-test-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-test-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-test-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-thread-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-thread-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-thread-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-timer-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-timer-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-timer-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-wave-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-wave-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-wave-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libboost-all-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-all-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-all-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-tools-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-atomic-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-chrono-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-context-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-coroutine-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-date-time-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-exception-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-filesystem-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-graph-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-graph-parallel-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-iostreams-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-locale-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-log-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-math-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-mpi-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-mpi-python-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-random-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-regex-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-serialization-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-signals-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-system-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-test-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-thread-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-timer-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-wave-dev:amd64 (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-all-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
```

Yet the boost folder is still **missing**.

**Why is happening?**

Comment: Will you edit your question and place the output of `sudo apt install --reinstall libboost-all-dev`?  Also, which version of Ubuntu are you running?  Whatever errors you get, if any, are important.

Comment: When you [edit] your post to provide the info L. D. James has requested, please also give the output of `dpkg -S atomic.hpp` (in case the boost headers are *somewhere*) and `lsb_release -a` and provide the contents of `/var/log/apt/history.log` and `/var/log/dpkg.log`. The site styles code in a way that limits their vertical height and makes them scrollable, so it'll probably be readable even if these are very long, but in case they're *too* long to be accepted (could happen with `dpkg.log`) or it's inconvenient to put them in your post, you could use https://paste.ubuntu.com/ and add links.

Comment: I found out what happened. I had to do `sudo apt-get purge libboost1.58-dev` and then `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`

Comment: Seems like just  reinstalling libboost-all-dev does nothing because it just calls the libboost1.58-* packages.

Comment: Looking at your output it appears that your first attempt at install didn't go.  The output you displayed is a normal output for an initial install.  Will you give the output of `ls -ld /usr/include/b*`?  It will hardly be more than two lines so a comment response should sufficiently verify the proper installation (or an indication that there is something wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Your Boost libraries were missing because you you, inadvertently didn't have it installed.  The command I provided you with in the comments was a verification of the installation.  If the libraries had been properly installed the output would have been just a couple of lines.

The first line of your output was:

```
0 upgraded, 27 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

This showed that 27 packages were missing and installed while processing the command.

Install/Reinstall command:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall libboost-all-dev
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,228 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 262406 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-all-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-all-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) over (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-all-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
```

Now that the **Boost** is properly installed the reinstall will only show 10 lines if reinstalled.  This commandline will show you your boost includes directory:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/include/b*
```

The output will be about two lines:

```
drwxr-xr-x 103 root root 12288 Jan 16 17:01 /usr/include/boost
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  1404 Nov 16 17:43 /usr/include/byteswap.h
```

Comment: No does not worked for me....

sudo apt install --reinstall libboost-all-dev
Preparing to unpack .../libboost-all-dev_1.58.0.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libboost-all-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) over (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libboost-all-dev (1.58.0.1ubuntu1) ...

/usr/include$ ls -ld /usr/include/b*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1404 Jan 14 21:49 /usr/include/byteswap.h
marius@HPP:/usr/include